# UML - Is an installer an artifact?

Tags: deployment, uml

I'm making a deployment diagram in UML for a windows application software. I wanted to know if an installer is an artifact and how should I draw the diagram exactly?

Do I only put the installer inside the node that represents a client machine, or I put not only the installer, but the components that it installs in association with installer?

Comment: As many Deployment Diagrams I saw there was no installer on them. I would say, that an Installer is not a part of a deployment, because you don't work on a deployed system with it (deployment diagram shows how a deployed system physically looks like, without showing the behavior of deployment). Hm, you could define a slice at the moment prepared installation and say that it is a deployment diagram of installation, is it what you want? Then I would take the second version (with associations) - it is more clear - you want describe the installation deployment.

Comment: So, maybe I should not put installer as artifact, but the installed components insted, right? Under the suppose that, yes, it is a deployment diagram, not installation one.

Comment: Installed and configured components on physical and operational infrastructure (<<device>>, <<execution Environment>>) form a deployed system. So I think yes - put installed components on that diagram. If you need to show the deployment process I would do it on another diagram. Here it looks like how a deployment (process) should be done: [Deployment Specification, Deployment Specification Dependency, Deployment Specifiation Association](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams.html). It shows what(<<artifact>>) and how(<<deployment spec>>, associations <<deploy>>) should be deployed.

Comment: but still, I did not see an installer as an <<artifact>> or a component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifacts physically represent your components. A component is a logically consistent part of your application.

So you have an artifact for your installer only if it is a part of your project. I mean if you designed your own installer, then it is an artifact because it is a part of the "result" of your software project. Yet even in this case it may not be very useful to have it appear in a deployment diagram, because you typically do not deploy an installer...

Otherwise it will not be an artifact. You will have artifacts for your installed components, not the installer itself.

Answer (score 1):

In UML terms your installer file *is* an artifact. Now whether you should or not show it in a diagram, it depends. A basic tenet of architecture documentation is that you should only produce architecture diagrams if there's anyone who'll benefit from it.

If the stakeholder of that diagram is someone who will install the software, then it may make sense to have the installer in the diagram. 
If the stakeholder of the diagram is someone who will simply try to configure or fix issues on the installed application, then you'd probably better show the installed artifacts.

In any case, the proper way to show that an artifact is deployed to a node is using the `<<deploy>>`stereotyped dependency. Example (from UML 2.5 specs, Fig. 19.3):
[image: Artifact-deploy-node]